# Can I publish my window form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've just finished a functional piece of code and would like to upload it to the Internet as freeware. It is just a Windows Forms application.
I used C# and Visual Studio 2008.
I want to know if it is legal to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing

Comment: You wrote it: you can do whatever the heck you want with it. If you use libraries that have restrictive licenses, you'll need to check those first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one can say it is legal without knowing exactly what the code does.   Perhaps it for example uses some patent without a license.

Another consideration is if you are using some 3rd party components without the proper license.  For example if you are offering your program freeware and you are using GPL, you need to also offer your program's source code.

In general, yes it's legal as long as you are using a licensed version of visual studio 2008 or are using Visual Studio Express edition.

You can also package the .NET redistributable package with your installer.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!
Its my first app that I am going to publish, I don't have much expierence with this subject...thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @HoNgOuRu: Congrats on finishing your project v1.

Comment: It should also be borne in mind that any third-party library's license needs to be checked whether it allows for redistribution.

Comment: @divo: I agree and added that and an example of it in the answer as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's legal.

As long as it's all your own work or you're not passing it off as your own work when you've used someone else's library then you can do what you want with the program.

Answer (score 1):

If your Visual Studio is lincesed, of course it is legal. You can use the built-in publish tool in Visual Studio, or use a software like [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) for the installation.

Comment: good tip, and one question about that....
If I use the installshield to make my app installable. Can I redistribute my application after the 30 days evaluation period of the installshield trial??

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely as long as your license of Visual Studio is legal.